# How to add an anchor at the end of paginate url in will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, will-paginate

Hello I have a problem while using `will paginate` gem.I want all pagination to be opened under my anchor tab which is "volunteers".

The link that will pagination generates is like `"/project_name?page=2"` but i want  to include my anchor tab too in the link.Like the link should be `"/project_name?page=2#volunteers"`. How can i get this link every time the user clicks on the next page?

In projects_controller.rb

```
def show
    @volunteers=@volunteers.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3 )
    end
```

In show.html.slim

```
=will_paginate @volunteers
```

Comment: @volunteers is a collection

Answer (score 2):

```
I got the solution finally that can add an anchor to the links so that the page redirects to the desired tab.In view replace
will_paginate @volunteers
with 
will_paginate @volunteers,:container => false,:params => {:anchor => "volunteers"}
```

This will generate a new url like '/projects?page=2#volunteers'.